# Can I spawn baby rabbits?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to spawn baby rabbits? I'm tired of having to breed grown rabbits to get a baby rabbit/bunny.

Comment: What research have you done before asking this question?

Comment: I've searched on google for a little while. I was a bit lazy so I barely read anything. But I'm going to read some more and hopefully find the command. Maybe this time I'll find an answer?

Comment: People who answer here are ordinary people who devote their time to help others, and no one likes to do someone else's job because that someone was lazy. Please help us help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All mobs that can be bred have a data tag called 'Age'.

> Represents the age of the mob in ticks; when negative, the mob is a baby. When 0 or above, the mob is an adult. When above 0, represents the number of ticks before this mob can breed again.

From [article on Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rabbit#Data_values)

The same article gives you a straight example of what you want:

```
/summon Rabbit ~ ~ ~ {Age:-20}
```

This will summon a baby Rabbit that will grow up in 1 second, as Age tag is in ticks, and game tick is 1/20 of a second. Naturally bred rabbits are spawned with Age:-24000, representing 20 minutes of childhood.

Answer (score -2):

You could breed 2 rabbits. I can't find command.
Also in case you want to know, here are the commands to spawn all types of rabbits.

```
/summon Rabbit ~0 ~1 ~0 {RabbitType:5} Salt and pepper rabbit
/summon Rabbit ~0 ~1 ~0 {RabbitType:4} Gold Rabbit
/summon Rabbit ~0 ~1 ~0 {RabbitType:3} Black And White
/summon Rabbit ~0 ~1 ~0 {RabbitType:2} Black
/summon Rabbit ~0 ~1 ~0 {RabbitType:1} White
/summon Rabbit ~0 ~1 ~0 {RabbitType:0} Brown
/summon Rabbit ~0 ~1 ~0 {RabbitType:99} Danger! Killer Bunny
```

Comment: Thanks for the commands! This could be useful for seeing all the different types of rabbits. And the killer bunny summon command would definitely be cool!